# Xcode 8 APNS push notification is not working with Development certificate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

Recently I upgraded my project to Xcode 8 ,APNS push notification is not working with Development certificate but it is working fine with the Distribution Certificate,Which was working fine with Xcode 7.3,I am enabling and disabling the sandbox perfectly.Any help will be appreciable

Comment: Did any of the answer helped you. Please respond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **Capabilities** and turn on **Push Notifications**

[image]

Other way to just use this tool
[NWPusher](https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher) and check with your dev and distribution certificates.

Finally, only the last option is to recreate the certificates.

I hope that should work.

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same issue.

What I did was to check certificates, keychain, provision profiles all ...
but the problem was still there,the switch in Capabilities/Push Notifications was ON then just I turn it OFF and turn ON again, and the issue dissapear.

I hope that will help.

Answer (score -1):

Your development certificates may have expired in the meanwhile. Also you could try recreating your certificates using fastlane (check out "cert" and "pem").